# Three.js loading fbx models

Tags: three.js

I use some examples from tutorial, and a cant understand this error.
And my texture files path in 'models/Textures/', and my fbx file path in 'models/' and program in automatically searching textures in path of fbx file. How can I set path to textures of this fbx model?

```
error: Uncaught TypeError: material.customProgramCacheKey is not a function
```

My code:

```
const loader = new FBXLoader();    
loader.setPath('assets/models/');
loader.load( 'Drone.fbx', (object) => {
mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( object );
    
const action = mixer.clipAction( object.animations[ 0 ] );
action.play();
    
object.traverse( ( child ) => {
   if (child.isMesh) {
      child.material.transparent = false;
      child.material.alphaTest = 0.5;
   }
});

scene.add(object);
    
}, undefined, e => {
   console.error(e);
});
```

Comment: faced same issue